# Claim in polynomial division in $R[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field, $f(x,y)\in \bar{k}[x,y]$. I claim that

> $f(x,y) = (x-a)g(x,y) +f(a,y)$.

I worked on it but could not show the equality. After that, I want to  show that
$$f(a,b) = 0 \implies f(x,y) = (x-a)g_1(x,y)+(y-b)g_2(x,y).$$

So I need some help to prove/disprove these. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: for some $g(x,y)$?

Comment: $g(x,y) \in \bar{k}[x,y]$

Comment: If consider $f$ as a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $y$ then you get $f(x,y)=(x-a)g(x,y)+r(y)$. Now send $x$ to $a$ and get $r(x)=f(a,x)$. (This comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem.) Then write $f(a,y)=(y-b)h(y)+f(a,b)$.